# Making class property optional WebAPI MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC5 WebAPI and i have a class as follows:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Sub { get; set; }
public List<Actions> Actions { get; set; }
```

(`Actions` is another custom class)

When client makes an API call they have to send the `Actions` property as null. Is there a way that the client may not send the actions property at all?

How could this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this public List Actions { get; set; } is optional by default.
if user/client don't specify it will be null.
Have you added any required field validations to it?

Answer (score 0):

If the client doesn't post actions. Then `Actions` at the time of model binding would be `null`. So there isn't any extra work from your side. In other words, if you post only `Name` and `Sub`, then `Actions` would be null.